# Define a mathematical function recursively

Tags: java, recursion

I have a mathematical function of integer division by 5

intDivByFive(N) = N/5

I have been told to define it recursively.

Can someone explain what exactly is it that I'm being asked to do here?

Comment: sounds like you are asked to make a function that is unnecessary complicated

Comment: Yes, recursive functions typically have at least one base case; a condition or set of conditions under which recursion can end, and the reverse process of returning up the call stack can occur.  In terms of this kind of function, there's only a base case - N is a single integer.  Was this some sort of PluralSite silliness?

Comment: Close enough. Revising for a test and one of the selected practice problems was to do this.

Comment: I've found boolean algebraic functions, such as intersection 
and difference, to be interesting and good practice, but don't know that this is of any use to you.  Anyway, good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you want to compute `N/5` recursively ... without using the `/` operator.  (This is unnecessary and impractical, but we can ignore that in this context.)

<sup>(Note in the rest of this answer I am renaming `N` to be `D` to align with the terminology used in the JLS.)</sup>

For the [Euclidian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) definition of the division `d / n`, we need to find `q` and `r` such that `d = q * n + r` where `0 ≤ r < |n|`.

Thus, for `d / 5`, `q` can be computed by the following:

```
   public int intDivByFive(int d) {
      if (d < 0) 
          return intDivByFive(d + 5) - 1;
      else if (d >= 5) 
          return intDivByFive(d - 5) + 1;
      else
          return 0;
   }
```

The function above works by repeatedly adding or subtracting `5` and counting the number of times you do that.  Additions are negative counts.

In theory, this works for all integers.  In practice it will fail with a `StackOverflowError` if the magnitude of `d` is too large.  (Java does not do [*tail call optimization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) in any existing version, at time of writing.)

---

**HOWEVER**, that's not what `/` means in Java.  In fact the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2) definition for division is:

> Integer division rounds toward 0. That is, the quotient produced for operands `n` and `d` that are integers after binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is an integer value `q` whose magnitude is as large as possible while satisfying `|d ⋅ q| ≤ |n|`. Moreover, `q` is positive when `|n| ≥ |d|` and `n` and `d` have the same sign, but `q` is negative when `|n| ≥ |d|` and `n` and `d` have opposite signs.

So the correct implementation for Java `/` semantics is:

```
  public int intDivByFive(int d) {
      if (d <= -5) 
          return intDivByFive(d + 5) - 1;
      else if (n >= 5) 
          return intDivByFive(d - 5) + 1;
      else
          return 0;
   }
```

---

We could debate endlessly which version is correct.  But it depends on what is meant by *"the mathematical function of division by 5"*.  We don't have the context to determine that.

Since mathematicians normally<sup>1</sup> take division to mean Euclidian division, I would argue that the first solution is more correct.  However, this is semantics.  The real point is that there are multiple different definitions of division.

<sup>1 - For example, my old copy of "Fundamentals of Abstract Algebra" by Neal H. McCoy (1972) uses the Euclidian definition but simply calls this division.</sup>

Comment: @Ecto I get `1` when I invoke (both versions of) `intDivByFive(8)`, which is exactly the same answer I get for `8 / 5`. (edit: I think Stephen changed the base case to return `0` instead of `n` since you commented)

Comment: @Slaw ... 1) I fixed the first problem.  2) The second problem is actually about what the "mathematical function N/5" actually means.  Ecto is assuming Java semantics ... which are NOT conventional mathematical semantics.  I (now) have given solutions for both Euclidean and Java division.

Answer (score 1):

As I said, it's unnecessary to make basic arithmetic operation a recursive function.

If you want a recursive function f(n) that gives the same result as n/5, you can use something like this:

```
int divByFive(int n) {
    if(n > -5 && n < 5) {
        return 0;
    }
    if(n > 0) {
        return 1 + divByFive(n - 5);
    } else {
        return -1 + divByFive(n + 5);
    }
}
```

Just add or subtract 5 until you reach 0 (or close to 0).

Comment: Oh ok, your code makes way more sense and it holds for all values of n. Much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Unnecessary from a practical standpoint, I agree.  But from an educational perspective a relatively simple to demonstrate/learn a specific concept.